# Custom serializers and deserializers in LiteDB v5.0.9

Tags: litedb

The release notes for LiteDB 5.0.9 says, "Custom serializers and deserializers can now be used even with basic BSON types. This is useful if you don't want to lose precision when storing DateTime."  But there doesn't appear to be any documentation describing how to do this.  Can someone point me to it or provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DateTime precision seems to be a [common issue with LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/420). [Issue 1765 provides the following solution](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1765#issuecomment-671473241):

```cs
var mapper = new BsonMapper();
mapper.RegisterType<DateTime>(
    value => value.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    bson => DateTime.ParseExact(bson, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind));
mapper.RegisterType<DateTimeOffset>(
    value => value.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    bson => DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(bson, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind));

using (var db = new LiteDatabase("instance.db", mapper))
{
    ...
}
```